# FF3 redirects from remote IP to localhost after form submission

Tags: firefox, redirect, localhost, browser-cache

I'm accessing another computer on the network, using the local ip (eg. 10.1.1.59:8080). Login page loads nicely but after form submission firefox (3) redirects to localhost instead of remote IP.

IE6/7/8 give no problems so it seems to be a firefox problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have the HTML of the form causing problems?

Comment: mm. good point - on FF3 it seems the form has
<form action="http://localhost:8080/web/guest.."> 

but Safari shows the same source as
<form action="http://10.1.1.59:8080/web/guest/">

The latter works ok.

Comment: Yep, seems to be. Flushing cache seems to remove the problem. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually i was wrong about the resolution. This wasn't a browser cache issue, but might have been related to jboss/tomcat - restarting them removes the problem for a while. I probably had restarted jboss when i flushed browser cache, and mistook the browser cache as the root cause.. I managed to recreate this problem on Safari & IE, so am leaning toward jboss being the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

`8080.` That's generally a proxy server port.

Answer (score 0):

Like shahkalpesh suggested above, seems to be related to caching.

Flushing cache removed the problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In this type of problem, the source is *usually* the server and its content.

Please edit your question to be more specific.

What URL did you type?

What did the source say?

What did your web server's access log say?